# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (450,1000,3) into shape (400,500,3)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I got an error,ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (450,1000,3) into shape (400,500,3) .I wrote codes,

```
img = cv2.imread("photo.png")
photo = cv2.imread("photo1.png")
img[0:400, 0:500, :] = photo
```

Before,I wrote codes

```
img = cv2.imread("photo.png")
photo = cv2.imread("photo1.png")
img_height = photo.shape[0]
img_width = bphoto.shape[1]
img[0:img_height, 0:img_width, :] = photo
```

but my before codes put photo's image always in the upper left corner on img.I wanna make a system put photo's image in  the center　on img.I really cannot understand why this codes cause error.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my code?

Comment: are you trying to overlay photo on img or rescale img based on photo's dimensions and channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
img[0:400, 0:500, :] = photo
```

You create a reference to a 400x500x3 matrix and are attempting to assign `photo` to it which gives you the error:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (450,1000,3) into shape (400,500,3)

This seems to imply that your `photo` is of size 450x1000x3.

Comment: thx ur answer.I wrote `img[0:450, 0:1000, :] = photo`,no error happens.But I cannot put photo in the center on img.How should I fix this?